# How can i manually add document-fields into local QueryDocumentSnapshot List

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have the following list

```
List <QueryDocumentSnapshot>  globalVideosUrls = [] ;
```

for example if we use the following

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
            .limit(1).get().then((value){
             globalVideosUrls.add(value)
        });
```

it will add as expected

but what if i want to manually add the following data into `globalVideosUrls`

**document id**

`00dcb026-3163-4ca0-859e`

**fields**

```
 'videoType':'peace'

 'url':'url'


.
```

`globalVideosUrls`.add(????)

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the type "QueryDocumentSnapshot" with QuerySnapshot and then you will get multiple docs and with there data also try this If any questions then ask.
thanks.

```
List<QuerySnapshot> globalVideosUrls = [];
List<String> videoUrlList = [];
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  globalVideosUrls.add(value);
});
globalVideosUrls.forEach((element) {
  element.docs.forEach((docELe) {
    print("data:- ${docELe.data()}");
    Map map = docELe.data() as Map;
    videoUrlList.add(map['url']);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks . but your answer is not related at all. besides i don't care of server side . i only have some data and i will add them into that List .. !

Comment: but this answer is based on storing the list of data in the local list which you asked the above.

Comment: i did not ask for how to storing the list since i already wrote the example of how to store it into local list THEN i ask my question of how to sort OR add some data . i need to sort data that not come from firstore . for example if we have String List like List<String> myList then need to add into it 'hello' so myList.add('hello') . how i do the same but with QueryDocumentSnapshot List

Comment: did you get it ? or edit my question for more explation ?